# Report Builder error "The request failed with an empty response"

Tags: reporting-services, report, builder

I am getting following error "The request failed with an empty response"
when I try to add a shared connection in Report Builder.

Same error happened when I try to save the report on SSRS.

Do you have any idea what can be the issue?

Note Creating the report with embedded and uploading the report from SSRS Portal I have no problem.

[error creating shared connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDIVF.png)
[error deploying on SSRS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEen6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot I think you're connected to the SSRS Web Portal URL. You need to change it to your SSRS Web Service URL. Just click 'Disconnect' in your status bar and then click 'Connect'. In the 'Connect to Report Server' dialog enter your SSRS Web Service URL which should be `http://<reportservername>/ReportServer`.